# How should you load 2 jquery javascript files to make sure they don't conflict, and the have them handle button clicks independant of each other?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a button click to pop up an alert.  The alerts pop up if I run alert ("works"); outside the  $(document).ready(function(){});

I am not sure what I am missing or if you have to load the second .js file differently?  I am using jquery 1.12.2.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="answer_audit_modals.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='../app/assets/js/audit/perform_audit1.js'></script>
```

This is inside the answer_audit_modals.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("test");
});
```

This is inside the perform audit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#upload_files123").click(function() {
    alert ("works");
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML where I do load bootstrap and it works for everything else:

```
<a href ="" "type="button" 
            class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
            id="#upload_files123"
            value="Test">test</a>
```

Here is the bootply trying to make the button click work:

http://www.bootply.com/D9onNOUNsR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files didn't conflict.

You're wrong in `id="#upload_files123"`. It should be just `id="upload_files123"`

Comment: That worked on the bootply, but on my web page when I click the button it tries to reload the page instead of make an alert.  So is it ok to use the $(document).ready(function(){}); for the second .js file too?

Comment: Yes you can use as many you want. To prevent from reloading page you should set `href='#'`

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href ="" "type="button" 
            class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
            id="#upload_files123"
            value="Test">test</a>
```

You use a `#` to reference an id, but don't actually include it in the id itself. just change your HTML to `id="upload_files123"` and it should work fine.